# How to Remove a matched line inside a file?

Tags: linux, shell

I need a shell script that should remove the matched pattern .

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: The name of the tool you want to use is sed.  `man sed` or `google sed`

Answer (score 1):

The command is

```
      sed  -i -e '/yourpattern/d' your_file
```

Comment: -i option stands for "in-place" editing. It is used to modify the file without the need to save the output of sed command to some temporary file and then replacing the original file. For example instead of:
Code:
sed 's/a/b/g' file > file.tmp; mv file.tmp file

you can do:
Code:
sed -i 's/a/b/g' file